# Find the minimum distance to a number from the elements of an array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, find, distance

What is an efficient way to find the smallest distance from a number lets say `2.5` in an array A in MATLAB?

The problem I have is that while I use the function min

```
     min(abs(A - 2.5))
```

I get an answer e.g 0.0053 I do not know what is the index of the number that gives the smallest difference after the subtraction.

I tried to add again the number so I get 2.5053 and when I try to do

```
     find(2.5053)
```

I get:

```
     Empty matrix: 1-by-0
```

Comment: for your find command, you'd want to use `find(A==2.5+minimum)`, where `minimum` is the result of the `min` operation

Comment: @Jonas But because of `abs`, it might have to be with a minus sign, instead of a plus sign

Comment: @LuisMendo: Oh, right. `find(abs(A)==2.5+minimum)`, then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the second output of [`min`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/min.html):

```
[value, index] = min(abs(A - 2.5));
```

Adding the number and then using `find` has several problems:

1. It's less efficient.
2. How do you know if you have to add or subtract? You are using `abs`.
3. Comparing doubles for equality is [not usually a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab), because of finite precision.